# How to enable hibernation on M1 Mac

Tags: big-sur, apple-silicon, hibernate

I am trying to enable Windows-like hibernation (powering off the device) on an M1 Mac mini. Current power mode configuration of any Mac can be displayed with `pmset -g` command, and this command's output does not include a `hibernatemode` entry. I try to enable hibernation with `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25` where `25` indicates power-off hibernation. Unfortunately this doesn't power the device off because the power light is still on when I put the device to sleep. Curiously enough, running `pmset -g` again still does not include a `hibernatemode` entry.

Is hibernation removed in new M1 Macs or macOS Big Sur? If not, what is the correct way to enable it?

Comment: Why is hibernation, as opposed to other forms of sleep, important on a desktop? Any reason you can't just shut it down?

Comment: I don't know if hibernate mode is removed on M1 Macs, but it is there for Intel Big Sur.  Mode 25 (even if it were to work) has not been advised for many years and there are potential FileVault issues.

Comment: The light is not a sleep indicator.  It is a power on indicator. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mac-mini-2020-m1-sleep-indicator-light-not-pulsating-in-sleep-mode.2273829/

Answer (score 5):

Hibernation on Mac m1 just released yesterday. Just update your mac to **MacOS Big Sur 11.3** to enable hibernation.

You can see the change log here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211896

to enable it you can use this command:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

just for your information based on `man pmset`

```
SAFE SLEEP ARGUMENTS
     hibernatemode supports values of 0, 3, or 25. Whether or not a hibernation image gets written is also dependent on the values of standby
     and autopoweroff

     For example, on desktops that support standby a hibernation image will be written after the specified standbydelay time. To disable
     hibernation images completely, ensure hibernatemode standby and autopoweroff are all set to 0.

     hibernatemode = 0 by default on desktops. The system will not back memory up to persistent storage. The system must wake from the
     contents of memory; the system will lose context on power loss. This is, historically, plain old sleep.

     hibernatemode = 3 by default on portables. The system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and will power memory
     during sleep. The system will wake from memory, unless a power loss forces it to restore from hibernate image.

     hibernatemode = 25 is only settable via pmset. The system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and will remove
     power to memory. The system will restore from disk image. If you want "hibernation" - slower sleeps, slower wakes, and better battery
     life, you should use this setting.

     Please note that hibernatefile may only point to a file located on the root volume.
```

So by default, the hibernate mode for a MacBook is 3, other device(imac, mac mini) is 0.

Actually, 3 is safe mode and uses very low energy also wake up faster, my MacBook can live for weeks just using this mode. So I recommended staying in default mode.

Comment: How can I use your answer "**to enable hibernation on M1 Mac**"?

Comment: @Mihai I updated my answer, hope that answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

See the attached image to create a shorcut in the Shorcuts app and add a keyboard shorcut to run it. This can be done in the (i) Menu -> Details Tab

[image: How to create a MacOS Hibernate Shortcut]

**SCRIPT UPDATE**

```
# Stopping services conflicting with hibernate
pkill SIGSTOP AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent
pkill SIGSTOP AMPDevicesAgent
tmutil stopbackup

# Change pmset settings
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
sudo pmset -a ttyskeepawake 0
sudo pmset -a tcpkeepalive 0
sudo pmset -a womp 0
sudo pmset -a powernap 0
sudo pmset -a networkoversleep 0

# Wait for OS sync new settings
sleep 3

# Call hibernate process
pmset sleepnow
# Wait 30 sec or more for macOS to hibernate

# Stops execution and continues when waking up. 
sleep 15

# Set pmset hibernatemode back
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3

# Loading stopped services
launchctl start com.apple.AMPDevicesAgent
killall Finder
```