# How to enable hibernation on M1 Mac Mini?

Tags: apple-silicon, hibernate

I did some research and found materials saying that Mac mini has this feature but I can't find it in pmset. There was an entry on changelog that big sur added hibernation.

[image: pmset]

Notes:

A related but different problem is here: [How to enable hibernation on M1 Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416108/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-m1-mac)
This problem is likely about macbook instead of mac mini. This is really not the same problem.

The reason why I want to enable hibernation mode on mac mini, which usually has a stable wall power and thus make hibernation mode pointless, is that I use my mac mini as a portable device, breaking this assumption.

Comment: Hibernation is for battery-powered laptops. If you want power off, turn it off.

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25`?

Comment: Insisting on the question being different without showing that it is different (e.g. by documenting your attempts) will not be enough to release the hold.